# What happened to the kbib package?

Tags: 11.04, kde, kubuntu

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu Natty, but I found there is not the kbib package any more.
Can anybody tell me why? Which is the easiest way to have kbib on Natty?

Answer (score 1):

The link to [their homepage](http://user.digisurf.com.au/~thachly/kbib) seems to be broken, which is listed on:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/kbib
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/kbib

A quick Google shows that the new website is located at http://users.tpg.com.au/thachly/kbib/

So it looks unmaintained (the last update dates from 3 November 2009). [Searching for `bibtex` in the packages search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=natty&searchon=all&keywords=bibtex) shows some alternatives, [`kbibtex`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/kbibtex) looks very promising and is made for KDE too:

> An application to manage bibliography databases in the BibTeX format. KBibTeX can be used as a standalone program, but can also be embedded into other KDE applications (e.g. as bibliography editor into Kile).
>
> KBibTeX can query online ressources (e.g. Google scholar) via customizable search URLs. It is also able to import complete datasets from NCBI Pubmed. It also supports tagging references with keywords and manages references to local files.
>
> BibTeX files can be exported into HTML, XML, PDF, PS and RTF format using a number of citation styles.

Answer (score 1):

**KDE 3**

The kbib is depending the deprecated KDE 3 packages. The last remaining packages of the KDE 3 libraries were removed 2011-08-19: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdelibs/+bug/794513 .

The kbibtex before the Precise were depending the KDE 3. The Precise has a new version depending the "new" KDE 4 & Qt 4. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kbibtex&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

**The Trinity**

The Trinity project is trying to keep the old KDE legacy alive.

Earlier - old KDE 3 apps:

- [How to install Amarok 1.4 on Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105387/how-to-install-amarok-1-4-on-ubuntu-11-10)
- [How can I copy quanta from 11.04 ubuntu to 11.10 install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75607/how-can-i-copy-quanta-from-11-04-ubuntu-to-11-10-install)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's off the repos, but you can find it [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/kbib).