# How to install Amarok 1.4 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, amarok

I want to install Amarok 1.4 on Ubuntu 11.10. I have done it before on Kubuntu 9.10, through some additional repository, but I am unable to locate such a repository for Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Amarok 1.4**

The Amarok 1.4 is depending /1/ the deprecated and removed KDE 3 libraries /2/.

You need to install the KDE 3 libraries first.

**Other options**

The Clementine /3/ is inspired by the Amarok 1.4. Clementine home: http://www.clementine-player.org/.

The Trinity /4/, /5/ is offering the KDE 3.5 desktop and support to the "old" KDE 3 apps.

**Links**

1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/amarok
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdelibs/+bug/794513
3. http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/clementine
4. http://www.trinitydesktop.org/
5. http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/11/02/1726228/kde-35-fork-trinity-releases-first-major-update

Comment: It seems that Clementine is solution. But for those who still want to install Amarok 1.4 it would be helpful if you explain how to install those KDE 3 libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably could install the kde3 libs & a older amarok-1.4 on 11.10 though it's possible it won;t function properly or certainly not as well as a self built version.

I'm not going to copy my how-to over here, mainly due to the need for a gcc patch that's attached to it's current location & is absolutely needed.

This has been designed to get the best possible amarok build & install with no broken packages. Please note that only ubuntu forum users can download the gcc patch, other patches in the how-to are available online.

If this answer is considered inappropriate then remove or request I do

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11377543

Answer (score 0):

**Q**

> But for those who still want to install Amarok 1.4 it would be helpful
>   if you explain how to install those KDE 3 libraries.

You could build them from the sources but the Trinity is trying to keep the KDE 3 alive.

Browsing to the http://www.trinitydesktop.org/...

**A Simulation**

**1)** Making a file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trinity.list. It has:

```
 deb http://ppa.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net/trinity/trinity-v3.5.13/ubuntu oneiric main
# deb-src http://ppa.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net/trinity/trinity-v3.5.13/ubuntu oneiric main
 deb http://ppa.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net/trinity/trinity-builddeps-v3.5.13/ubuntu oneiric main
# deb-src http://ppa.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net/trinity/trinity-builddeps-v3.5.13/ubuntu oneiric main
```

**2)** Adding the GPG signing key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net --recv-keys 2B8638D0
```

.

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.mWSEdDcvAv --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net --recv-keys 2B8638D0
gpg: requesting key 2B8638D0 from hkp server keyserver.quickbuild.pearsoncomputing.net
gpg: key 2B8638D0: public key "QuickBuild Trinity Desktop Environment" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

**3)** Updating the package database:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**4)** Looking the "old" version of the amarok:

[image]

```
apt-cache show amarok-trinity
```

.

```
Package: amarok-trinity
Source: amarok-trinity
Priority: optional
Section: kde
Installed-Size: 6456
Maintainer: Timothy Pearson <*****>
Architecture: i386
Version: 4:3.5.13-0ubuntu9+r1260411+pr5~oneiric
....
Description: versatile and easy to use audio player for Trinity
 Amarok tries to be a little different, providing a simple drag and drop
 interface that really makes playlist handling easy.
 .
 Features include:
 - rapid playlist creation, with drag and drop from a directory view
 - nice playlist browser for your existing playlists (PLS or M3U formats)
 - collection-indexing support, for smart browsing and playlist creation
 - possibility of accessing media via kioslaves, allowing you to play
 via smb:// or fish:// (normal streams are of course supported)
 - inline ID3 tag editing, capable of retrieving tags via MusicBrainz
 - album cover support: automatically displays album covers from the
 filesystem, or downloaded on the fly
 - miscellaneous audio effects, including crossfading
 - easy bindable global shortcuts, rich DCOP interface
 - On-Screen Display (OSD), on track change or at keypress
 - iPod and iRiver support
 - Last.fm stream playing support (if ruby is installed)
 - Track "mood" display (requires moodbar package installed)
 .
 Support for libvisual visualization plugins is also compiled in (you need
 to have libvisual-0.4-plugins installed to be able to use it).
```

**5)** Installing the Amarok-trinity (only simulation)

```
apt-get install -s amarok-trinity
```

.

```
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

The following extra packages will be installed:
  amarok-common-trinity amarok-engine-xine-trinity kdelibs-data-trinity
  kdelibs4c2a-trinity launchpad-integration libarts1c2a-trinity libifp4
  libnjb5 libpq5 libqt3-mt libtqtinterface xbase-clients
Suggested packages:
  libqt0-ruby1.8 python-qt3 amarok-engines-trinity moodbar fam perl-suid
  libgnome2-0 libarts1-akode libqt3-mt-psql libqt3-mt-mysql libqt3-mt-odbc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amarok-common-trinity amarok-engine-xine-trinity amarok-trinity
  kdelibs-data-trinity kdelibs4c2a-trinity launchpad-integration
  libarts1c2a-trinity libifp4 libnjb5 libpq5 libqt3-mt libtqtinterface
  xbase-clients
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

To install the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install amarok-trinity
```